# How do I add schema markup to individual WordPress posts without using plugins?

Tags: functions

I'm not a web developer and I'm not a very techie person either, so I'm sorry if any of the following information below wouldn't make much sense.

I'm currently trying to add schema markup for articles on my site.

I used Google's markup helper to generate the code for one post and inserted it into the  section of my WordPress' theme's header.php file. I validated the markup using Google's markup testing tool and the markup test result came back valid except for a missing headline.

My concern is if I'm going to add schema markup code to my theme's header.php file everytime I publish a new post, wouldn't that contain too much data eventually? (I have about 40 articles on my site and will be adding more). I'm under the impression that if there's too much code or text in there, it might end up affecting my site's performance in terms of speed (do correct me if I misunderstood).

Because of the worry above, I'm trying to find a way to add schema markup to individual posts, but without using any plugins if possible. My problem is I don't know how to do it because there's no  in the HTML code of my individual posts where I can insert the markup code. (individual posts only have this code "" before the content).

Can anyone teach me how to get around this or if there's any particular code template that I can use to add schema markup code to individual WordPress posts?

Thank you. (Sorry for the very long post. I just wanted to provide more context to my issue)

Update #2 - Code that I see from my single.php file:

```
<?php
```

get_header(); ?>

```
<div id="primary" class="full-featured-content-small content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">

    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );

        if ( get_theme_mod('amazorize_post_navigation_options', 'navigation_enable') == 'navigation_enable' ) :
            the_post_navigation();
        endif;

        if ( get_theme_mod('amazorize_related_post_options', 'related_post_enable') == 'related_post_enable' ) :
            amazorize_related_posts();
        endif;

        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
            comments_template();
        endif;

    endwhile; // End of the loop.
    ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the same type of Schema information about every post, you can do this by creating a child theme.

(Instead of editing your theme directly, you create a style.css file that references the parent, and copy just the files you need to modify into that child theme. This way, when you update your parent theme, your customizations aren't lost.)

Which Schema you want to use, what information you want to include within it, and what theme you're using will all determine exactly how and where you include the details. Here's a basic example to add "[Article](http://schema.org/Article)" schema to your Posts.

style.css

```
/*
Theme Name: Schema Test
Template: twentytwenty
*/
```

Your style.css file can be extremely basic. The Theme Name will tell WordPress "Hey, here's a theme the user can activate," and the Template refers to the parent theme so WP knows which parent to reference. You will need to change the Template to be the folder of whatever theme you're using. Here, the parent is the "Twenty Twenty" theme, and we refer to it by "twentytwenty" because that is what the folder containing the theme is called. Adjust as needed. Upload this file to /wp-content/themes/schema-test/. Voila, you have a Child Theme you can activate - though you won't notice a difference since you're not actually overriding anything yet.

Next you need to identify which parent theme files contain code that you want to change (or add to). Each theme is a bit different, though typically you will find Posts handled in the "single.php" file. So, copy the "single.php" file from the parent theme into your "schema-test" folder and then edit it.

Let's say your file currently looks like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<main>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            the_content();
        endwhile;
    endif; ?>
</main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

To make this an Article, you would identify whatever HTML element wraps the content. In this case, there's a <main> element around just the content. (In many themes, there's also a sidebar, and you'd want to exclude that - so there might be an inner div or something more specific in your theme.)

All you do is add the itemscope itemtype code for your desired Schema:

You now have a Schema Article. Next you'll need to determine what information is available - such as the title, the author, etc., etc. This is again very theme-specific, because some themes may include the title inside the <main> element, while others may include it inside "header.php". So, you always have to determine one HTML element that includes all of the data you want to mark up, which sometimes means adding your own HTML element, such as a <div>, which may span multiple files. And, when you're editing files like "header.php", keep in mind all content types use that file, so if you only want to mark up your Posts, you'll need to add conditionals such as

```
<?php if is_singular('post') {
// add schema
} ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response!

The code in Update #2 shows the code that I see in my child theme's single.php file. 

Should I just paste the markup code after the "main" opening tag and before the "while" part?

Would there be a difference if I'm using JSON-LD instead of microdata? I'm under the impression they're a bit different?

What would happen after I was done pasting the markup code to the single.php file? Would I need to add new code using the same template to the single.php file whenever I have a new post or is there some other place that I'd need to update?

Comment: Sorry if I had too many questions. My understanding of lines of codes, what exactly they can do, and how they interact with other codes is pretty limited.

Comment: Since your theme uses template parts, you should actually edit the "content" template part, which appears to be in a /template-parts/ folder. The Schema website gives examples for various formats, from JSON to microdata. Because this site is intended as a resource for everyone, it's often not possible to give a full answer of the specific code you'll need to use - it's meant more to give you the right general direction. You may want to join FB groups such as Intermediate WordPress where perhaps someone will assist with more specific code.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thank you for the extra tip! I will look into this group.